# Python pinecone pod not completely full

Tags: python, vector, pinecone

I am using pinecone in order to store 768-dimensional vectors in a vector database. From the docs, I read that the free tier allows to store up to 100,000 vectors. However, in my case, there seem to be only 1,466 vectors. Also, the dashboard reports a pod fullness of 0.0%.

In my client code, I upserted around 86,000 vectors, but only 1,466 are uploaded. I mention that I also add some metadata for each vector, namely an integer encoded as a string. Below is a screenshot from the dashboard, showing the number of vectors and pod fullness.

[image]

How could I upload all 86,000 vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Upserting can be complicated and easy to skip loads. I have had good luck using the Vector Vault vector database. The saving and loading is a lot easier. You can check it out on Github. https://github.com/john-rood/vectorvault